# Matlab reshape two vectors in a particular way

Tags: matlab

I have two vectors and I want the numbers to follow one each other. By this I mean:

```
a = [5 6 4 2 1];
b = [4 2 1 3];
```

Vector b can be smaller than a by one or can be the same length
I want to get

```
c = [5 4 6 2 4 1 2 3 1];
```

I tried to use reshape but gave up. So I just implemented the loop. 
But is there a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sliced assignment:

```
% prepare c
c = zeros(1, length(a) + length(b));

% assign a
c(1:2:length(a)*2) = a;

% assign b
c((1:2:length(b)*2)+1) = b;
```

Note: This solution does not verify if either `a` or `b` are too short. Too long `a` or `b` will give an error though.

AFAIK `reshape` is only usable to change the dimensions of a single array/matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use simple concatenation and reordering?

```
>> a = [5 6 4 2 1];
>> b = [4 2 1 3];
>> c = [a b];                 % initialize by concatenation
>> c([1:2:end 2:2:end]) = c   % reorder by sliced re-assignment 

c =
    5     4     6     2     4     1     2     3     1
```